# Moved legacy classic asp web site to django app but having trouble with django URL redirect app - old URLs with parameters get 500 error

Tags: django

I moved a 20 year old classic asp web site to a django app recently.  Google Search Console is showing 500 errors for tons of very old URLS with parameters like /somefile.asp?ID=1234&name=some-name.  Most of these URLS I don't even care about - they are really old but would rather they result in 404 than 500.   Some do relate to newer content and in theory I could redirect to new django pages but when I try to redirect them using the django redirect app, the site shows 500 errors - like the ? either stops the pages from ever getting to the redirect middleware or the redirect app doesn't like the "?".  How can I redirect these urls so I don't get 500 errors?  Is there a way in a view to say:

if the full url path is x
   redirect to full url path y

I have looked all over stack overflow and elsewhere and can't find this exact problem or a way to write a view like this. I did try the solution here (exactly) because it seems closest to my issue, but it did not work for me for this exact problem: [Django's redirects app doesn't work with URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192484/djangos-redirects-app-doesnt-work-with-url-parameters)

An example would be /profiles/?adid=134&v=857

The error with debug true is:
DoesNotExist at /profiles/
BusinessCategory matching query does not exist....

So it is trying to match this URL:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.view_category_list, name='view_category_list'),
```

before it ever gets to the /?

Relevant view code:

```
def view_category_list(request, slug):
    try:
        category_detail = BusinessCategory.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except BusinessCategory.DoesNotExist:
        category_detail = None
    if category_detail:
        --code here is all working fine so removed it to get to the issue--
    else:
        raise Http404
```

I hoped raising the 404 would call up the redirect app to do its job at redirecting to a specific url but it doesn't - it just shows the custom 404 when debug is False.  Anyway, the 404 is better than the 500 for SEO purposes but I still would prefer being able to actually redirect some of the URLs to relevant content.

Comment: 1. Can we see your urls.py as well as a real URL (you can remove the domain name if you need privacy) which does not work?

Comment: 2. A 500 internal server error is just the information that there is an error. What is the error actually?

Comment: 3. Does it give an error in production, I.e. with debug set to false? 404s give the error in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks so much Matthew! I updated the question to answer some of your questions -  I get the 500 error in production (and locally) with debug set to false.  This is my first time ever posting on stack overflow and what you can't see above is the slug:slug - going to try and fix that.

Comment: Can we see the business category view code as well? You probably aren't checking properly for whether the category exists or not.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewGaiser - you are exactly right.  I wasn't checking properly to see if the category existed. I have added the code that I have now that is working better but not exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again!